# Where are the Spring MVC validation error codes resolved?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, validation, error-code

I am attempting to write [validators](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html) under the Spring MVC framework, but there is a glaring omission in the documentation. When calling passing an error to the [Errors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html#rejectValue%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) object most of the methods expect an String parameter named errorCode. These errorCodes, if I understand correctly serve as stand ins for specific error messages. But I can't for the life figure out where these codes are mapped to.

Here is an example of what I am referring to from Spring MVC's Javadoc;

```
 public class UserLoginValidator implements Validator {

    private static final int MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 6;

    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
       return UserLogin.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
       ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "userName", "field.required");
       ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "password", "field.required");
       UserLogin login = (UserLogin) target;
       if (login.getPassword() != null
             && login.getPassword().trim().length() < MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH) {
          errors.rejectValue("password", "field.min.length",
                new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH)},
                "The password must be at least [" + MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH + "] characters in length.");
       }
    }
 }
```

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: in 2020, the documentation for that is still incomplete :-D https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#validation-conversion

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm using the default message resolver.

In my `dispatcher-servlet.xml`, I have

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
</bean>
```

and then in the top level of my classes directory I have a text file called "messages.properties" that contains mappings like this:

```
error.firstname.null=Please enter your first name.
error.lastname.null=Please enter your last name.
```

If you wanted to use a custom MessageCodesResolver you can implement the MessageCodeResolver interface and then define your resolver for a given controller like this:

```
<bean id="myController">
  <property name="messageCodesResolver" ref="myMessageCodesResolver" />
</bean>
```

There isn't currently a way to define a custom `MessageCodeResolver` globally; there's an [enhancement request for that here](http://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5187).  One approach using  bean inheritance to make all controller beans inherit from one controller bean definition, is described [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=46336).

Comment: Thanks for the information, this gives me enough to make use of my validator. But in the interest of learning what would I do if I wanted to rewire in a custom MessageCodeResolver, where would I go? Also just for prosperity ResourceBundleMessageSource's javadoc is at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/ResourceBundleMessageSource.html.

Comment: If you want to use a custom MessageCodeResolver, you can assign one for a given controller.  One approach, then, is to use bean inheritance to make all controller beans inherit from one controller bean definition, as described here:  http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=46336    There isn't currently a way to define a custom MessageCodeResolver globally; there's an enhancement request for that here:  https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5187

Comment: For reference, the global custom `MessageCodeResolver` feature was eventually implemented in Spring 3.1 (2011). See also [SPR-6506](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6506).

Answer (score 3):

They are resolved by your [MessageSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html) and a [MessagesCodeResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/validation/MessageCodesResolver.html).

[Here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/validation.html#validation-conversion) is the relevant section in the reference manual:

> Outputting messages corresponding to validation errors is the last thing we need to discuss. In the example we've shown above, we rejected the name and the age field. If we're going to output the error messages by using a `MessageSource`, we will do so using the error code we've given when rejecting the field ('name' and 'age' in this case). When you call (either directly, or indirectly, using for example the `ValidationUtils` class) `rejectValue` or one of the other reject methods from the `Errors` interface, the underlying implementation will not only register the code you've passed in, but also a number of additional error codes.

Comment: a default instance (DefaultMessageCodesResolver) is used if you don't specify one. You should just need to register a MessageSource though and that will be used automatically.

Comment: How do you register a MessageSource? I see messageCodesResolver as bean property. But is there a way to set a MessageCodeResolver as universal across the entire application?

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource

Answer (score 1):

For some reason if you want to resolve the messages in the Controller similar to form:errors jsp tags then you can do the following:

```
   //result is BindingResult
   List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();
   List<ObjectError> allErrors = result.getAllErrors();
   for (ObjectError error : allErrors) {
      String message = messageSource.getMessage(error, null);
      errors.add(message);
   }
```

Comment: I want to point out that MessageSource can be @Autowired in the controller